# Multiple path execution through single curl request

Tags: json, scala, curl, spray

i have the following code to execute.i can execute both path blocks with two curl requests but i want to execute both path blocks with single curl request or can i redirect from 1st path state to secod path 1:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import spray.routing.SimpleRoutingApp
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
object Server1 extends App with SimpleRoutingApp{
    implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()        
    startServer(interface="localhost",port = 8080){
        println("Listening...")         
        get{
            println("incoming..")
            path("state"){
                complete{
                    "in first path"
                }
            }   
           path("1"){
                complete{
                    "in another path"
                }
            }   
       } 
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want a curl syntax solution; curl localhost:8080/{state,1} should do work

Comment: What is preventing you from replacing "in first path" with a function, say `runState()`, that you call from both `path("state")` and `path("1")`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need both the `state` and `1` paths independently, and also need a path which performs both updates (presumably for performance reasons) you can add a third path which performs both functions with one request

```
def doFirst = ...
def doOne   = ...

   get{
        println("incoming..")
        path("state"){
            complete{
              doState()
            }
        }   
       path("1"){
            complete{
                doOne()
            }
        }
       path("stateAnd1"){
            complete{
                doState()
                doOne()
            }
        }   
   }
```